# how to fix error in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

i just doing now laravel 5.2 steam authentication
i am followed this link

```
https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth## Heading ##
```

i got a error in composer

```
"Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamServiceProvider::class class not a found"
```

i have add the composer.json file in

```
    "invisnik/laravel-steam-auth": "2.*"

    and composer install and then add 
     app.php
        Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamServiceProvider::class,
```

but this error will be display

```
    "Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamServiceProvider::class class not a found"
```

how can fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the class or declare it on the fly using by adding a backwards slash

```
\SteamServiceProvider
```

Eg:

```
\SteamServiceProvider::method()
```

And if you are adding a new package, make sure to run the following composer command to recatch the files.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: @murugesh if the answer is useful you can accept it as solution which will help further users.

Comment: ya s this answer is useful

Comment: @ArunCode - +1 from my side